# Cannot retrieve data from SQL Server using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a stored procedure that joins 2 tables and would only need a few fields from both the table.

```
ALTER PROC GetViewers 
@postId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT e.Email, e.ImagePath, CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.MiddleName, ' ', e.SurName) AS 'FullName'
    FROM Posts as p
    JOIN Employees as e
    ON p.AuthorId = e.EmployeeId
    WHERE p.Id = @postId
END
```

I am using an entity framework core that is injected so to update, create, and everything I have to use this kind of syntax..

**For Employee Table**

```
var results = _context.Empkoyees.toListAsync();

var posts = _context.Posts.ToListAsync();
```

and this results and posts give me all the properties of Employees and Posts. But if I use a stored procedure using this

```
var postId = new SqlParameter("@postId", id);
var x = _context.Posts.FromSql("GetViewers @postId", postId).ToList();
```

I get an error that some of my required fields are not present. I don't want to use linq. Just the stored procedure please.

Comment: you need to make some of your required fields present - what it means? well depends on **what is the error, which you didn't provide**

Comment: I have multiple required fields for both tables. The sp that I require for the joined table is only 3. That's my question, How do I get the values without doing that. What's with the downvote?

Comment: Could you please add an error. Also, try to exec this SP directly in mssql. Also please attach a c# model with mapping.

Comment: also obviously you procedure doesn't return post but rather employee when `Posts.FromSql` obviously expects Post ... obvious fix use `Empkoyees.FromSql` and return all fields needed by `Employee`

Comment: Even if I use Employees, I would still get the same error because it would look for the same required fields.

Comment: then return them `SELECT e.*...` FullName can be `public string FullName => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Name, etc...)` on C# side

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a parameter:

```
var post = new SqlParameter("@postId", postId);
var x = _context.Posts.FromSql("GetViewers @postId", post).ToList();
```

Comment: I have that. I just didn't include it. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add the parameter for the stored procedure in a different way.

have a look at the documentation below 
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

```
var x = _context.Posts.FromSql("GetViewers @postId", postId).ToList();
```

To something like this:

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@postId", postId);
var x = _context.Posts.FromSql("GetViewers @postId", param).ToList();
```

So the problem wasn't in the code but apparently Entity Framework Core has some limitations with stored procedures

1. Result must be an entity type. This means that a stored procedure must return all the columns of the corresponding table of an entity.
2. Result cannot contain related data. This means that a stored procedure cannot perform JOINs to formulate the result.
3. Insert, Update and Delete procedures cannot be mapped with the entity, so the SaveChanges method cannot call stored procedures for CUD operations.

Comment: I have that already. I just didn't include it. Please see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that there are a number of limitations with stored procedures and EF core.  https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx 

Result cannot contain related data. This means that a stored procedure cannot perform JOINs to formulate the result.